# Replacing column values from one table into another without adding another column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `services` and `users`. Below are their schema

**services**

```
id  | service_type | created_by

1   | test  | 1
2   | test  | 1
3   | test  | 1
4   | test  | 2
```

**Users**

```
id | username | password

1   | user1@example.com | .......
2   | user2@example.com | .......
```

output

```
id | service_type | created_by

1   | test  | user1@example.com
2   | test  | user1@example.com
3   | test  | user1@example.com
4   | test  | user2@example.com
```

In `service` table `created_by` are the `id` from the `user` table. What I want in output is to display all the data from the `services` table including all the column names but replace all the ids in `created_by` with the `username` from the `users` table

Below is my query, but problem is that, it is adding another column called `username`. I don't want another column, just replace the column value from user table into services table. Is something possible?

```
select s.*, u.username from services o JOIN users u ON s.created_by = u.id;
```

**Reason**

I am currently connecting graphql to my database and I need to add `Query`to get all information, but instead of ids in `created_by`, I need username as giving ids to user is not good idea.

Comment: * but problem is that, it is adding another column called username* No. Your problem is in `limit 1` - what you have added it for? And another problem is in an asterisk usage - replace it with definite columns names which needed really.

Comment: @Akina limit 1 was just for the testing. There are over 6000 records so can't pull all the records. I will remove it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Akina I want all the columns from services only and replace the column value from username from user into created_by of service.

Comment: You are buying N Apples, and you want one of the apple to taste like Orange, but you don't want to replace one Apple with Orange. Sorry, but this is just to explain you. I am pretty sure you know what * is doing here. You need an alias and specify all your columns of service table. In general without identifying that Apple you can't replace it with Orange right? Same concept apply here.

Comment: *I want all the columns from services only **and replace** the column value from username from user into created_by of service.* This is NOT ALL. Don't fool yourself or anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL, you have to explicitly select the columns you want if you want to exclude any one column. This means that you can't use the wildcard `s.*` to select every column dynamically without selecting the `created_by` values.

There's also no way to "replace" a value in a SQL query. The best you can do is select a different column/value and alias it with the column name you want.

Here's how you'd have to write this query (*notice "as created_by" in the select clause*):

```
select s.id, s.service_type, u.username as created_by
  from services s
  join users u on s.created_by = u.id;
```